# #line keyword in C

Tags: c, line

I am trying to understand some code and I've come across a keyword that I've never seen before. I tried to google it, but haven't found anything regarding it as well.

```
char *valtext;
#line 1 "Values.l"
#define INITIAL 0
#line 2 "Values.l"
int reserve(char *s);
#line 388 "lex.val.c"
```

I've included the entire block hoping that perhaps someone can help me understand this chunk of code. I can't find any files on my system named "Values.l" and this chunk of code is located in the "lex.val.c" file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this seems to explain it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34dk387t(v=vs.80).aspx (just realized you're asking about C and not C# so this may or may not apply after all)

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b5w2czay%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, Googling "line" isn't going to be very useful, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line directive:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b5w2czay%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: It's a directive, not a pragma.

Comment: The referenced web page refers to the C# `#line` directive, and includes forms that are not standard in C (or C++).

Comment: Fixed; now it refers to Microsoft's C/C++ documentation, which actually follows the Standard quite closely.

Comment: Link is broken. Removing the end of the link works thought: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5w2czay.aspx

Answer (score 11):

A `#line` directive sets the compiler's setting for the current file name and line number.  This affects the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` symbols, the output generated by a failing `assert()`, and diagnostic messages (errors and warnings).  It's typically used by the preprocessor so that error and warning messages can refer to the original source code, not to the output of the preprocessor (which is typically discarded by the time you see any messages).

It's also used by other tools that generate C source code, such as lex/flex and yacc/bison, so that error messages can refer to the input file rather than the (temporary) generated C code.

The definitive reference is [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (pdf), section 6.10.4.

A line of the form

```
#line number
```

sets the current line number.  A line of the form

```
#line number "file-name"
```

sets both the line number and the file name.  You can also generate one of these two forms via macro expansion; for example:

```
#define LINE 42
#define FILE "foo.c"
#line LINE FILE
```

Answer (score 4):

The `#line` directive is for the use of preprocessors, so that the original line number of the source can be communicated to the C compiler.  It makes it so that error messages from the compiler properly refer to line numbers the user will understand.

For example, line 12 of your mycode.c may go through a preprocessor, and now be line 183 of mycode.tmp.cc.  If the C compiler finds an error on that line, you don't want to be told the error is on line 183 of mycode.tmp.cc.  So the C compiler needs to be given "original coordinates" of each line.  The `#line` directive does this, telling the compiler the current line number and filename to use in error messages.

Answer (score 0):

That code has gone through the pre-processor and as such is marked up by one stage of a compiler, intended to be consumed by another stage of the same compiler. The features that it uses aren't intended for your use.

The files that it references may be temporary files created by the compiler as it runs.

Comment: Typically the file referenced by a `#line` directive is the original source file.  The point is to *avoid* referring to temporary files.  And it's perfectly reasonable to use `#line` yourself if you have a tool that generates (temporary) C source from some other input file; lex/flex and yacc/bison do this.  But for more purposes, you can ignore it.

Comment: I just said that because he says he doesn't have "Values.l". Looking more closely at the question, `Values.l` is clearly a file created by running `lex` -- in fact, this is a `lex.yy.c` file he's looking at!

Answer (score 0):

This is done so that [the line number changes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html).

This is done in order to show the line numbers of the Lex input file, for example, in error messages and warnings. Because Lex generates C code, without `#line` directives compile errors and warnings wouldn't be of any value.